# Convert int to binary, the perform bitwise operations on it

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to convert an int to binary, and then perform bitwise operations on the binary.

My current method is to take the int, call `to_s(2)` on it, but then I'm left with a binary string.

Any advice on what I should do?

Comment: *Everything* is in binary. The only difference is in textual representation. In a computer, there is no such thing as a decimal or hexadecimal number. Only binary.

Comment: Well, there are a number of libraries or languages which have a real "decimal" type, which may actually use a different internal representation (typically to avoid problems associated with traditional floating-point representations). However, the plain "integer" type is almost always binary internally.

Comment: (And yes, I realize that any representation boils down to binary at the lowest level ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`the_number.to_s(2).split('').map { |x| x.to_i }` # convert the number to binary array

Comment: Explain why this is the right answer. Providing a correct answer helps a lot more if the OP also learns from it.

Comment: I see the point here. Can map the string split across the string, then for each character convert that to an int.

Comment: @BrianA do you mean the_number.to_s(2).to_i ?

Answer (score 6):

Simple integers are stored as binary in nearly every major programming language (including Ruby). So, you can do your bitwise operations on the integers themselves:

```
>> 6 | 5 # bitwise or
=> 7
>> 6 & 5 # bitwise and
=> 4
>> 6 ^ 5 # bitwise xor
=> 3
>> 6 >> 2 # right shift
=> 1
>> 6 << 2 # left shift
=> 24
```

(Edit: this appears to be my 1000<sup>th</sup> answer.)